# Multiple selection dropdown list in excel

Tags: excel

I've got workbook with many (over 50) sheets in it. In 49 sheets, there is more or less dropdown lists in E column. If there is dropdown list, the source of list depends on C cell in the same row. So depending on eg. C11, E11 will be dropdownlist1, dropdownlist2 or blank. Now in each of 49 sheets, I want to make globaly dropdownlist2 to be multiple selection list. Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
     If Not Sh.Name = "Dane" Then
        With Sh
            Dim Oldvalue As String
            Dim Newvalue As String
            .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            On Error GoTo Exitsub
            ' the check to catch a change of single cell only
            If Not Target.Rows.Count > 1 And Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
                ' check that this cell in column "E" (concept #2)
                If Not Intersect(Target, .Columns(5)) Is Nothing Then
                    'check if this is validation data cell
                    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
                      GoTo Exitsub
                    Else: If .Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
                      Application.EnableEvents = False
                      Newvalue = Target.Value
                      Application.Undo
                      Oldvalue = Target.Value
                        If Oldvalue = "" Then
                          Target.Value = Newvalue
                        Else
                            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                              Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
                            Else:
                              Target.Value = Oldvalue
                            End If
                        End If
                     End If
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Now if this code is in This_workbook it seems not to work, and if I put the whats below with into specific sheet vba, `Worksheet_Change` it works. Also, for now, this code will work for both, dropdownlist1 and dropdownlist2. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try commenting out the on error line to see what's going on. And what does "seems not to work" mean?

Comment: `.Target.Value` is not correct, that first dot should not be there.

Comment: I removed the dot, and nothing happens. There is no error at all. It looks like this function do nothing. Also, if I remove dot from Protect line, there is error, so function is executed.

Comment: Okay. I've figured out first issue with the code. I was refering to one cell for all the time, and `Not` statement in `If Not Target.Rows.Count > 1 And Not Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then` line was missing. However, there is still one question remaining. Is there a way to check if in cell eg E14 there is dropdownlist1 or dropdownlist2?

Comment: This is a data validation dropdown list?

Comment: Yes, created with named range.

Comment: You can use the `formula1` property viz `target.validation.formula1`.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the output of Formula1? Is it named range name or formula which is in validation data?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Not by the computer till tomorrow 

Comment: It should show the named range assuming you are using a list.

Comment: It does, if there is no condition in data valiadtion. For this specific cell Im using `=indirect(b14)` function to create dropdown list and `target.validation.formula1` returns me `=indirect(b14)` value. If im trying to evaluate that formula by `Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1)` to go through, I get mismatch error.

Comment: So why not just refer to the contents of B14 if that contains the range name?

Comment: Well, that probably would work, but just out of curiosity, is it possible with `evaluate`?

Comment: Ordinarily yes, but with DV what are you evaluating? If the validation formula is just "=List" then what does it mean to evaluate it? I guess that is why it errors. There might be a workaround though.

Comment: Im evaluating `=indirect(b14)`.

Comment: Yes but what does that actually mean?

Comment: So my multiple selection list is in e14 cell. dropdown list in e14 is created by data validation with `=indirect(b14)` formula. b14 is empty, list1, list2, or few no list value. Now, if b14 is list1 I want e14 list to become multiple selection list. I can use `Target.Validation.Formula1` on b14 cell, as You pointed out, but Im wondering if I can precache it in e14 cell.

Comment: You can use the contents of B14 to add your validation in E14 with VBA but not sure I follow what you're doing. DV doesn't allow multiple selection AFAIK.

Comment: Multiple selection is in code from question but the check there `If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
                      GoTo Exitsub` makes the list multiple no matter what list it is.

Comment: OK yes I see now. Think the discussion has gone on long enough now. You basically need to build in a check to see if the range referenced is list1 or not.

Comment: Yes. And if I would be able to `Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1) ` in e14 cell, that would be it.

Comment: Maybe that's the question. If there's a way to do it someone here will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my code was mistake. All the time I was refering to single cell, which was checked by: `If Not Target.Rows.Count > 1 And Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then` but after And operator Not were missing. In that way, to works, I should edit more than 1 cell in separate columns. The code below is fixed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
     If Not Sh.Name = "Dane" Then
        With Sh
            Dim Oldvalue As String
            Dim Newvalue As String
            .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            On Error GoTo Exitsub
            ' the check to catch a change of single cell only
            If Not Target.Rows.Count > 1 And Not Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
                ' check that this cell in column "E" (concept #2)
                If Not Intersect(Target, .Columns(5)) Is Nothing Then
                    'check if this is validation data cell
                    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
                      GoTo Exitsub
                    Else: If .Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
                      Application.EnableEvents = False
                      Newvalue = Target.Value
                      Application.Undo
                      Oldvalue = Target.Value
                        If Oldvalue = "" Then
                          Target.Value = Newvalue
                        Else
                            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                              Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
                            Else:
                              Target.Value = Oldvalue
                            End If
                        End If
                     End If
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use `If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then`, or better yet `Target.Count = 1`