# How to get excel drop down list source in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im using [VBA code to create multiple selection drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261013/multiple-selection-dropdown-list-in-excel). The code will make each drop down list in target cell become multuple selection list with function:

`If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then GoTo Exitsub`

The source of drop down list in target cell is `=indirect(b14)`, and b14 is another drop down list (single selection). Now if b14's value will become list1, Id like to make my target's cell list become multiple selection list. In any other case I want it work in normal excel way. I've tried to precache the list source with `if Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1) = "=list1" then`
but I get mismatch error for `Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1)`.
How can I do it?

EDIT:
There are some example screenshots from my worksheet, not to misunderstand it's construction.

[image: A1:A5 named range list1, B1:B5 named range list2, B14 data validation list =list1]
A1:A5 named range list1, B1:B5 named range list2, B14 data validation list =list1

[image: D14 data validation list with =INDIRECT(B14) formula]
D14 data validation list with =INDIRECT(B14) formula

Comment: Try removing the call to `Evaluate`. Instead, it could be `If Target.Validation.Formula1 = "=list1"`

Comment: `Target.Validation.Formula1 ` returns `=indirect(b14) ` so it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you trying to create [Excel Data Validation–Create Dynamic Dependent Lists](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/09/02/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/)?

Comment: I already have dependent lists, created not by macro, but by `=indirect(b14)` formula. So b14 is normal, data validation, named range list, and d14 is `=indirect(b14)` list, so once its `=List1`, once `=List2` and once its empty. Im trying to check whether d14 list is `=List2` or not.

Comment: Short answer: `Evaluate` won't work with `=ADR.POŚR(B14)` and I guess this is exactly what `Formula1` returns (although the first comment states otherwise). One solution is to find English equivalent, the other is to add an additional named range with this formula and use it as validation source.

Comment: So either I'll have to use english version of office or find another way to determine D14 list source? As far as I know, Im not able to use english formulas in non english office, yup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using the `Worksheet_Change` event means that every worksheet change is going to run your code, so `Target` could be any range not just B14. The assumption that you can use the `Target.Validation.Formula1` property on any cell is wrong because cells that do not have validation will not have this property available.

[image]

Secondly, you are doing this:

> ```
> If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then GoTo Exitsub
> ```

I believe that you are making the assumption that this is referring to cells within the `Target` range but it really refers to all the cells with validation within the entire sheet. Try this code to clarify that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngValidation As Range
    
    Set rngValidation = Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)

    Debug.Print Target.Address
    If Not rngValidation Is Nothing Then Debug.Print rngValidation.Address
End Sub
```

You can see in your Immediate window that no matter what cell you are editing the `rngValidation` will always point to all the validation cells within the worksheet.

Thirdly, you are doing this:

> ```
> If Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1) = "=list1"
> ```

which won't work because `Evaluate("=Indirect(B14)")` simply returns an array and not a String as you are assuming.

Finally, if I read the question I understand that you want the list in cell D14 to be changed based on value in B14 but you keep referring to the `Target` as D14. If B14 is changed then B14 is the `Target`, not D14. D14 can only be the `Target` if you change D14. That's just how the Event works.

Since I am not clear on what you want, I am assuming two scenarios:

1. Cell B14 is changed and you want to update D14
2. Cell D14 is selected and you want the list to be updated before you click the dropdown

**Scenario 1** - Cell B14 is changed and you want to update D14 (or other cells)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim rngValidation As Range
    Dim rngValidTarget As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range

    Set rngValidation = Target.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    Set rngValidTarget = Intersect(Target, rngValidation)
    If rngValidTarget Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

    'validTarget could still be a multi-cell range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rngArea In rngValidTarget.Areas
        For Each rngCell In rngArea
            If rngCell.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                If rngCell.Validation.Formula1 = "=List1" Then
                    Debug.Print rngCell.Address & " - Validation: " & rngCell.Validation.Formula1
                    'Do whatever logic you need to update other cells linking to this one
                    '
                    '
                    '
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
    Next rngArea
    On Error GoTo 0
ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Scenario 2** - Cell D14 (or equivalent) is selected and you want the list to be updated before you click the dropdown

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rngValidation As Range
    Dim rngValidTarget As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim listFound As Boolean

    Set rngValidation = Target.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    Set rngValidTarget = Intersect(Target, rngValidation)
    If rngValidTarget Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

    'validTarget could still be a multi-cell range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rngArea In rngValidTarget.Areas
        For Each rngCell In rngArea
            If rngCell.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                Set rngList = Nothing
                Set rngList = Evaluate(rngCell.Validation.Formula1)
                listFound = False
                If Not rngList Is Nothing Then
                    listFound = (rngList.Name.Name = "List1")
                End If
                    
                If listFound Then
                    Debug.Print rngCell.Address & " - list found"
                    'Do whatever logic you need to update rngCell
                    '
                    '
                Else
                    Debug.Print rngCell.Address & " - list not found"
                    'Do whatever logic you need to update rngCell
                    '
                    '
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
    Next rngArea
    On Error GoTo 0
ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**

You can use the following code to translate formulas:

```
Private Function TranslateFormulaToUS(ByVal formulaText As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With GetBlankEditableCell
        .Formula2Local = formulaText
        TranslateFormulaToUS = .Formula
        .Formula = vbNullString
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function GetBlankEditableCell() As Range
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Static blankCell As Range
    '
    'Re-use, if still blank
    If Not blankCell Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(blankCell.Value2) Then
            Set GetBlankEditableCell = blankCell
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    '
    'Find a Blank cell
    For Each wSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set blankCell = GetEditableBlankCellFromSheet(wSheet)
        If Not blankCell Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next wSheet
    Set GetBlankEditableCell = blankCell
End Function

Private Function GetEditableBlankCellFromSheet(wSheet As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim rngBlanks As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngBlanks = wSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngBlanks Is Nothing Then Set rngBlanks = wSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    '
    'Check if Worksheet is Macro Protected
    If (wSheet.ProtectContents Or wSheet.ProtectDrawingObjects _
    Or wSheet.ProtectScenarios) And Not wSheet.ProtectionMode _
    Then
        For Each rngCell In rngBlanks
            If Not rngCell.Locked Is Nothing Then
                Set GetEditableBlankCellFromSheet = rngCell
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next rngCell
    Else
        Set GetEditableBlankCellFromSheet = rngBlanks.Cells(1, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

And now you can replace something like:

```
Set rngList = Evaluate(rngCell.Validation.Formula1)
```

with:

```
Set rngList = Evaluate(TranslateFormulaToUS(rngCell.Validation.Formula1))
```

**EDIT 2**

If you would like to avoid the translation mentioned in **EDIT 1** then you could use a dynamic relative named range as mentioned in the comments.

Let's start with the current layout (I presume I got it right):

[image]

Named range `List1` is a local scope range:

[image]

Named range `List2` is also a local scope range:

[image]

The B column (rows could vary from sheet to sheet) has data validation set to List1:

[image]

Let's create a third named range called RemoteDV:

1. Select first cell in column D that has the validation
2. Create a LOCAL named range and add the formula `=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$B8)` (or whatever row you are on - i.e. first row in both B and D column that has validation - I have 8 here). **NOTE**! Do not use an absolute address (i.e. locking the row with `=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$B$8)`) because we want the named range to work for the entire D column

[image]

Now, let's link the new named range to validation:

1. Select all cells in column D that have validation
2. Link to the named range you have just created

[image]

The end result is that you do not have to translate the formula anymore.

You also do not need Evaluate anymore:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rngValidation As Range
    Dim rngValidTarget As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim listFound As Boolean
    Dim formulaText As String
    Dim nameList As Name

    Set rngValidation = Target.Worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    Set rngValidTarget = Intersect(Target, rngValidation)
    If rngValidTarget Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

    'validTarget could still be a multi-cell range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rngArea In rngValidTarget.Areas
        For Each rngCell In rngArea
            If rngCell.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                Set rngList = Nothing
                formulaText = rngCell.Validation.Formula1
                If Left$(formulaText, 1) = "=" Then
                    formulaText = Right$(formulaText, Len(formulaText) - 1)
                End If
                Set nameList = Nothing
                Set nameList = rngCell.Worksheet.Names(formulaText)
                Set rngList = nameList.RefersToRange
                
                listFound = False
                If Not rngList Is Nothing Then
                    listFound = (rngList.Name.Name = "'" & rngList.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & "List1") _
                        Or (rngList.Name.Name = rngList.Worksheet.Name & "!" & "List1")
                End If
                    
                If listFound Then
                    Debug.Print rngCell.Address & " - list found"
                    'Do whatever logic you need to update rngCell
                    '
                    '
                Else
                    Debug.Print rngCell.Address & " - list not found"
                    'Do whatever logic you need to update rngCell
                    '
                    '
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
    Next rngArea
    On Error GoTo 0
ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: B14 and D14 are for example use only. In my workbook, there is about 50 sheets. Each sheet have the B14/D14 issue starting from row 14 to row X where X is different for each sheet. BX cell determines list source for DX cell (`=INDIRECT(BX)`). I want to run my code for each DX cell if list source is List1. As @basodre attempt to fix my code failed, probably because I'm using polish excel version, so as @BrakNicku mentioned, Evaluate function will fail to work with polish version of `=indirect(BX)`.

Comment: @FilipFrątczak I've added an **EDIT 1** section to address the language issue

Comment: I see it might work, however, would it be able to check dropdown list range without using evaluation?

Comment: @FilipFrątczak I do not think so. Even if you wrap the indirect into a named range you would still need to use Evaluate but at least this way you probably wouldn't need the translate. Of course it all depends on how many named ranges you would need to create (too many would cause other issues). You could use one per sheet I guess if you create a dynamic and relative named range (i.e. select cell D14 and create named range equal to INDIRECT of B14 without any $ signs so that when you fill the entire D column with a list validation you could just use the same named range for the entire column).

Comment: @FilipFrątczak, are you reusing the same names, List1 & List2, on all the sheets?  Might there be another issue with Named Range Scope?

Comment: @Profex, in each sheet Im using the same names. List1 and List2.

Comment: @FilipFrątczak Have you tried the translation? Also, have you tried using a dynamic named range for the data validation?

Comment: Not yet. The translation code is like to tilt at windmills for my purpose, however probably it will work. Ill try it by the weekend. How can I use dynamic named range here?

Comment: @FilipFrątczak I have added an **EDIT 2** section to show how to create the dynamic named range.

Comment: @Cristian Buse That seems to be the clearest way to solve the problem. Thank You.

Comment: @FilipFrątczak Great. I've tried to make the code as general as possible so, you might want to restrict the event to just the D column.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Below is a simple block of code that should do what you need. First, I created a data validation drop down in cell A1. Next, I created a list named List1 and pointed it to a range of values. Next, I set the List -> Formula of the data validation to be `=INDIRECT(B14)`. And finally I entered the text `List1` in cell B14.

I ran the below test script to see what my output was.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rangeWithDropdown As Range
    
    Set rangeWithDropdown = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    
    Debug.Print rangeWithDropdown.Validation.Formula1
    Debug.Print Evaluate(rangeWithDropdown.Validation.Formula1).Name
    Debug.Print Evaluate(rangeWithDropdown.Validation.Formula1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Names("List1").Value
End Sub
```

My output was the following:

```
=INDIRECT(B14)
=Sheet1!$D$1:$D$4
True
```

When requesting the formula alone, it returns `=INDIRECT(B14)`. When evaluating the formula, and returning the name, it returns the range that I established. And finally, when testing for equality against the named range, it returns true.

Is my understanding correct? Can you try running this code against your workbook (update the data validation cell reference), and then tell me which line throws an error?
END EDIT

---

The reason that your code isn't working is that `Evaluate(=indirect(B14))` does not return the name of the range, but rather the address of the range. So, if `List1` refers to Range("A1:A10"), then the `Evaluate` function will return Sheet1!Range("A1:A10"). When you try comparing a string ("list1") to a range, you get the type mismatch error.

One option is to compare the range returned against the expected range of "List1". For example, the following code might work:
 `If evaluate(activecell.validation.formula1).name = activeworkbook.Names("List1").Value`

Comment: If I use `If evaluate(activecell.validation.formula1).name` with cell where list is created by data validation `=namedrange` it works, but if I use it on cell, where list is created with data validation formula eg. `=indirect(b14)` I get runtime error.

Comment: Anything? Im still trying to reslove this question...

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the issue. I created a test workbook, within which I added a data validation dropdown on cell "A1". Next, I created a list and named it "List1". Finally, in the validation List -> Formula, I entered `=INDIRECT(B14)`, and then entered List1 in cell B14, and everything seemed to work. I'll edit my post above to show my code snippets.

Comment: So if I put this in my code, in workbook_sheetchange, and by changing specific cell I get `=list2
=Data!$C$2:$C$14
False` for cell where data validation is created by `=list2`, and for cell, where data validation is created by `=indirect(b14)` i get runtime 424, object requied error with line: `Debug.Print Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1).Name` and debug output: `=INDIRECT($B14)` Maybe the problem is, that b14 cell is data validation drop down list `=list2` cell? Thats seems the only thing to be different from your example.

Comment: I changed my cell `B14` to also be a validation drop down, and my code still worked. Even when I put it into my `Workbook_Sheetchange` event. Is `Target` pointing at a correct cell with validation? I'm wondering if there's something I'm misunderstanding. Can you post an image of the worksheet (or an example)? To clarify, cell B14 has a validation list, and one of the options is "List1"? And List1 is also the name of a range? And the other cell with validation points to `=INDIRECT(B14)`?

Comment: I've added screenshots to the question. I hope the construction of worksheet is now clear.

Comment: Also, I've triend on newer excel and have the same issue.

Comment: @FilipFrątczak I've matched everything on my workbook up with yours, and I'm still not generating any errors. Is it possible to also include the code the entire code that you're running, and I'll see if that clears anything up.

Comment: I've just created new workbook the same as on screenshoots in question. Then, I put vba code into`This_workbook`. The code is: `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print Target.Validation.Formula1
    Debug.Print Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1).Name
    Debug.Print Evaluate(Target.Validation.Formula1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Names("List1").Value


End Sub` If I hit B14 it works, if I hit D14 I have the error.

Comment: I think I duplicated the issue. If `B14` contains an entry that is NOT it's own named range, this will throw the `424` error. For example, if I select `Cat` in B14, then run the function against D14, it will throw an error. Reason is that `Evaluate(Target...` expects that there is a named range that matches the value in `B14`. If no named range, it is trying to build a range that doesn't exist. You may have to error check for this type of condition.

Comment: But I also get this error if b14 value is named list.  Above it would be List2 value.

Comment: I've tried to check outcome of indirect function. I've created new file with List1 and List2 ranges, A6 value was just List1, and B7 value `=indirect(A6)`. It gave me `#VALUE` error in cell, but if I F9 the formula in B7 it gives me `={"List2";"asd";"das"}`. Maybe thats causing my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I see there has been a lot of work by others. I didn't want to "steal" their solutions so i didn't read them completely. I hope my contribution won't be out of place. I humbly proceed to post my answer.

If in the column with the first drop-down lists (column B) the said drop-down list are already present, then our "List1" outcome will be a possible value. This solution checks if such value is "List1" and creates the second drop-down list accodingly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblStartingRow As Double
    Dim DblEndingRow As Double
    Dim RngFirstDropDownList As Range
    Dim RngSecondDropDownList As Range
    Dim RngRange01
    Dim StrTrigger As String
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'VARIABLES SETTINGS - Start'
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    'StrTrigger will be the value that if found in the first drop down _
    list will trigger the creation of the second drop down list.
    StrTrigger = "List1"
    
    'DblStartingRow is the first row that will possibly contain one of _
    our drop down list.
    DblStartingRow = 14
    
    'DblStartingRow is the last row that will possibly contain one of _
    our drop down list.
    DblEndingRow = Rows.Count
    
    'Setting RngFirstDropDownList and RngSecondDropDownList to match _
    the entire columns where our lists of drop-down lists will be found.
    Set RngFirstDropDownList = Range("B:B")
    Set RngSecondDropDownList = Range("D:D")
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'VARIABLES SETTINGS - End'
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    'Resetting RngSecondDropDownList to cover only the rows we need to _
    cover according to DblStartingRow and DblEndingRow
    Set RngSecondDropDownList = RngSecondDropDownList.Resize(DblEndingRow - DblStartingRow + 1, 1).Offset(DblStartingRow - 1, 0)
    
    'Checking if Target intersects with RngSecondDropDownList. If there _
    is no intersection, the subroutine is terminated. Otherwise RngRange01 _
    is set as such intersection.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RngRange01 = Intersect(Target, RngSecondDropDownList)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If RngRange01 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    'Covering each cell in RngRange01
    For Each RngSecondDropDownList In RngRange01
        
        'Setting RngFirstDropDownList as the cell in the column of first _
        drop-down lists at the same row of our (possible) second drop-down _
        list.
        Set RngFirstDropDownList = Cells(RngSecondDropDownList.Row, RngFirstDropDownList.Column)
        
        'Focusing RngSecondDropDownList.
        With RngSecondDropDownList.Validation
            
            'Removing validation.
            .Delete
            
            'Checking if RngFirstDropDownList contains StrTrigger.
            If RngFirstDropDownList.Formula = StrTrigger Then
                
                'Adding the dropdown list.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                     Operator:=xlBetween, _
                     Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & RngFirstDropDownList.Address & ")"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End If
            
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```

To be put in the sheets' module, it will activate everytime the selection is changed. If the selection intersect with the range with the second drop-down list, it will insert such drop-down list for each cell in said intersection. Works for single and multiple cell selection. I've set every possible parameter i could think of as a variable that can be changed in the first part of the subroutine after declarations. This should do what the question was asking.

Then again, if the question wanted the second drop-down list to be created only when:

1. there is a first drop-down list in the proper cell and
2. said first drop-down list had a specific Validation.Formula1

then the code i'd suggest is this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblStartingRow As Double
    Dim DblEndingRow As Double
    Dim RngFirstDropDownList As Range
    Dim RngSecondDropDownList As Range
    Dim RngRange01
    Dim StrTrigger As String
    Dim StrValidation As String
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'VARIABLES SETTINGS - Start'
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    'StrTrigger will be the formula that if found in Validation.Formula1 _
    of the first drop-down list will trigger the creation of the second _
    drop down list.
    StrTrigger = "=List1"
    
    'DblStartingRow is the first row that will possibly contain one of _
    our drop down list.
    DblStartingRow = 14
    
    'DblStartingRow is the last row that will possibly contain one of _
    our drop down list.
    DblEndingRow = Rows.Count
    
    'Setting RngFirstDropDownList and RngSecondDropDownList to match _
    the entire columns where our lists of drop-down lists will be found.
    Set RngFirstDropDownList = Range("B:B")
    Set RngSecondDropDownList = Range("D:D")
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'VARIABLES SETTINGS - End'
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    'Resetting RngSecondDropDownList to cover only the rows we need to _
    cover according to DblStartingRow and DblEndingRow
    Set RngSecondDropDownList = RngSecondDropDownList.Resize(DblEndingRow - DblStartingRow + 1, 1).Offset(DblStartingRow - 1, 0)
    
    'Checking if Target intersects with RngSecondDropDownList. If there _
    is no intersection, the subroutine is terminated. Otherwise RngRange01 _
    is set as such intersection.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RngRange01 = Intersect(Target, RngSecondDropDownList)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If RngRange01 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    'Covering each cell in RngRange01
    For Each RngSecondDropDownList In RngRange01
        
        'Setting RngFirstDropDownList as the cell in the column of first _
        drop-down lists at the same row of our (possible) second drop-down _
        list.
        Set RngFirstDropDownList = Cells(RngSecondDropDownList.Row, RngFirstDropDownList.Column)
        
        'Focusing RngSecondDropDownList.
        With RngSecondDropDownList.Validation
            
            'Removing validation.
            .Delete
            
            'Checking if RngFirstDropDownList contains a drop-down list _
            based on StrTrigger.
            On Error GoTo CP_No_Drop_down_List
            If RngFirstDropDownList.Validation.Formula1 = StrTrigger Then
                
                'Adding the dropdown list.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                     Operator:=xlBetween, _
                     Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & RngFirstDropDownList.Address & ")"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End If
CP_No_Drop_down_List:
            On Error GoTo 0
            
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This code is similar to the previous one but it will in fact check if there is a first drop-down list based on the Validation.Formula1 specified. Note that if you want the second drop-down list be created acconding to `StrTrigger` and not to the actual indirect reference of the first drop-down list value, you can substitute the line

`Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & RngFirstDropDownList.Address & ")"`

with the line

`Formula1:=StrTrigger`

Comment: So the difference is that with your code I don't create data validation in D column, but it will be created by macro if B column cell is List1, yup? Basicly, that is the best solution in my case, however it's not the best answer for the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: My answer has 2 codes. The first one does what you just described, the other checks if the cell in column B has a data validation based on a specified string (formula). Anyway thank you for your appreciation. :)
.